# List files on non-default filesystem in Scala

Tags: scala, hadoop, azure-blob-storage

I need to access multiple Azure blobs in the job. Example: for a simple enough task like listing files on filesystem, can be simply achieved for *defaultFS* by:

```
val hc = ss.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration
val fs = org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(hc)
val files = fs.listFiles(new Path(path))
```

I simply want to achieve the above on non-defaultFS. I thought this could be achieved by just having relevant credential for other fs in `core-site.xml` (or adding in configuration by doing `hc.put("fs.azure.account.key.<blob_name>.blob.core.windows.net", value)` and using the raw *path* (`wasbs://<container_name>@<blob_name>.blob.core.windows.net/...`) but that gives *FileNotFoundException*.

How can I access the non-default fs (of course, without overriding *defaultFS*)?

Comment: Adding the configs or the URI is correct. Note: Spark isn't required here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me in Scala against S3 and HDFS. It should work on Azure too. I think you are missing URI while initializing filesystem.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, FileUtil, Path}

val sparkContext //create spark context or obtain from Spark session
val configuration = sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration
val fs = FileSystem.get(new URI(<url to blob storage>), configuration)

fs.listFiles(<pass org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path>, boolean <recursive or not>)

//You can also use
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.listFiles(java.io.File)
```